# Run JavaScript if form.is_valid() with variable from views.py

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to use a javaScript to print a variable to a Dymo printer. I have tested the javaScript code and it works, but I don't know how I'm going to access and run this javaScript from my views.py. Maybe I can do it from the template, but the variable that I try to print contains some database information that is created when the form is valid.

Please ask if anything is unclear! Thanks!

### Views.py

```
def CreateWasteView(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateWasteForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        waste = Waste_Item(material=form['materialList'].value(), height=form['height'].value(), width=form['height'].value())
        waste.save()
        waste.code = form['materialList'].value() + str(waste.pk)
        waste.save()
    return render(request, 'waste/home.html')
    else:
        form = CreateWasteForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'waste/new.html', context)
```

### Template

```
{% extends "waste/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Waste-Item!</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startupCode(code) {
  dymo.label.framework.trace = 1;
  var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
  if (printers.length == 0)
    throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";

  dymo.label.framework.getPrintersAsync().then(function(printers){
    // Successful result, printers variable has a list of all supported by the DYMO Label Framework
console.log(printers);
  }).thenCatch(function(error){
// Error
  });

   var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
                    <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
                        <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
                        <Id>Address</Id>\
                        <PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
                        <DrawCommands>\
                            <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1440" Height="1440" Rx="180" Ry="180" />\
                        </DrawCommands>\
                        <ObjectInfo>\
                        <TextObject>\
                            <Name>TEXT1</Name>\
                            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
                            <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
                            <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
                            <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
                            <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
                            <IsVariable>False</IsVariable>\
                            <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
                            <VerticalAlignment>Top</VerticalAlignment>\
                            <TextFitMode>AlwaysFit</TextFitMode>\
                            <UseFullFontHeight>False</UseFullFontHeight>\
                            <Verticalized>False</Verticalized>\
                            <StyledText>\
                                <Element>\
                                    <String>BARCODE</String>\
                                    <Attributes>\
                                    <Font Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False"\
                                    Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                                    <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
                                    </Attributes>\
                                </Element>\
                            </StyledText>\
                        </TextObject>\
                         <Bounds X="336" Y="132.900024414063" Width="2265" Height="345" />\
                        </ObjectInfo>\
                    </DieCutLabel>';

  var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
  label.setObjectText("TEXT1", code);
  label.print("DYMO LabelWriter 450 Turbo"); // This is the NAME of the 
printer which i found 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the variable to your javascript from the view after the form is valid?

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do that?

Comment: Is your javascript written in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the required variable to the javascript through the views for this purpose. Example:

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    waste = Waste_Item(material=form['materialList'].value(), height=form['height'].value(), width=form['height'].value())
    waste.save()
    waste.code = form['materialList'].value() + str(waste.pk)
    waste.save()
    value = '' #the value you want to pass
return render(request, 'waste/home.html', {'value':value})
```

Then in the template you can obtain the value using `{{ value }}`. Then you may pass this value to the function to be called.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use your solution to create my own that suited my problem!